# texorpdfstring in addcontentsline - Using math mode in an unnumbered subsubsection

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, hyperref, warnings, bookmarks

I have an issue to use the `\texorpdfstring` command in `\addcontentsline`. This is the minicode :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}[Les symboles \texorpdfstring{$\forall$}{forall} et \texorpdfstring{$\exists$}{exists}]

\subsubsection*{Les symboles \boldmath$\forall$ et \boldmath$\exists$}

\end{document}
```

So first I have this "reference" in my toc which depends of where the title is in the document:

[image]

then I have this subsubtitle copy generated by the `\addcontentsline` command :

[image]

and the bookmark level warning... About the bookmark level warning I've tried to add thoses lines :

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\toclevel@<foobar>}{0}
\makeatother
```

But it's doing nothing...

There is definitely something I'm doing wrong here but really no idea what it is..

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you use brackets instead of braces. Also you must change tocdepth to show a subsubsection.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{Les symboles \texorpdfstring{$\forall$}{forall} et \texorpdfstring{$\exists$}{exists}}

\subsubsection*{Les symboles \boldmath$\forall$ et \boldmath$\exists$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't belive I've spent so much time on a wrong syntax, it was very nice to you to answer :)